# My new motherboard Asus Z10PE-D16 WS doesn't start

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard, power-supply

I have purchased the following components :

- Asus Z10PE-D16 WS
- 2 CPU : Intel Xeon E5-2658 v3
- 2 Fans : Noctua NH-U12S
- Power Supply : EVGA SuperNOVA 1300W GOLD
- Ram : Kingston
  KVR21R15D4K4/64 RAM 64Go 2133MHz DDR4 ECC Reg CL15 DIMM Kit (4x16Go)
  288-pin

I assembled the components without the RAM, because I'm still waiting for it.

When I press power on to test the mobo the CATT LED light (red) and the fans started for one second then the machine immediately shuts down.
I don't think the absence of RAM do that?
The 24+8+8-pin power plugs are connected.

Answer (score 0):

You really need the RAM.
Most UEFI motherboards (like yours) won't get to post without RAM.

Old school BIOS based motherboards could usually boot far enough to complain about the missing RAM, but UEFI is a mini-OS by itself and really needs (in most cases) RAM for its own operation.

Comment: Ok, I will wait until tomorrow to make sure that the RAM is the problem. Thank you :)